# Varnish & WordPress Port :8080 in URL

Tags: wordpress, centos, port, varnish

I've installed Varnish on a server running several WordPress sites and I find that sometimes, and this is only every few times I login to a given site, that :8080, the port that Apache is now using, show up after the TLD in the address bar of my browser.

This is a problem as it makes saving many changes in the WordPress backend impossible and can create a lot of frustrated users.

I've ready several posts on this subject already, but none gives a really clear answer as to where this can be resolved.

I'm using the "Option 2" from this site as my .vlc:

http://crlog.info/2011/09/10/install-and-configure-varnish-3-0-1-cache-with-wordpress/

All of my WordPress instances are current and my server is running the following:

- CentOS 5.7 x86_64 (64-bit)
- Apache 2.2.19
- MySQL 5.1.54
- PHP 5.3.5

Is an an application-level change needed? Is this an Apache setting?  Do I modify Varnish?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what exactly is being cached since this is an issue with varnish and it has a lot of granularity.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the VLC file is caching everything except the WordPress backend and then setting a whole slew of purge rules so that the cache can be selectively cleared when content is changed or new content it published.  The backend shouldn't be cached at all, which may be why I'm seeing the :8080 as I'm getting passed directly to Apache when logging in.

Comment: What additional information do I need to provide to make this an answerable question?

Comment: can I have a look at the link causing this

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind Varnish to public IP whereas bind Apache to 127.0.0.1 (via `Listen` directive).

That way you can run both on the same port 80. Change Apache from 8080 to 80. It will allow you to avoid any port related issues whatsoever.